# Sort list by keyword matched in data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have a long list with basic JavaScript search. 
The search functions uses regex to test if certain conditions are met, and hide those do not meet. I am trying to sort the list and prioritize those found in attribute 1, follow by items that have keyword matched in attribute 2. Scenario described as below.

**My list**

- Chocolate Caramels
- Garlic Mayonnaise
- Tomato Egg
- Scrambled egg

**Currently** - *when I search for `egg`, it returns the list as below*

- Garlic Mayonnaise
- Tomato **Egg**
- Scrambled **Egg**

**Aiming for** - *This is the result I am looking for*

- Scrambled **Egg**
- Tomato **Egg**
- Garlic Mayonnaise

---

As we can see from the list, `Garlic Mayonnaise` does not have `Egg` in its product title, but search returns true because `egg` is found in the data attribute, as shown in below.

`<li productname="Garlic Mayonnaise" data-desc="Contains egg">Garlic Mayonnaise</li>`

Is there any way we can sort the list by keyword found in title and followed by those keyword found in data attribute?

My search function as in below

```
let productList = $('#productListUL li');
$.each(productList, function(_index, product){
    let self                        = $(product),
        productId                   = self.attr('productid'),
        productName                 = self.attr('productname'),
        productDesc                 = self.attr('data-desc');

        if (
            regex.test(productId) ||
            regex.test(productName) ||
            regex.test(productDesc)
        )
        {                        
            self.removeClass('hidden');
        }  
        else{
            self.addClass('hidden');
        }

});
```

Comment: Add an attribute to the element, say, `priority`. Set that to a different number based on which attribute was matched. Sort the list by that new attribute. I would suggest separating the data from the DOM elements though; then you can more easily do the searching and sorting and just rerender the list based on an array of objects.

Comment: It's not clear from the exampel,. what is `productList` containing? Objects or elements?

Comment: @Twisty Elements (`let self = $(product); self.removeClass('hidden')` the formatting makes it hard to read, IMO).

Comment: @Twisty, sorry for the confusion. `productList` is element `$('#productListUL li')`.

Comment: Can you paste some sample list entries?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make use of the order of operations. It means taking two passes at the list, and it will give you the results you want.

```js
$(function() {
  function sortList(d, lObj) {
    var c = [];
    $.each(d, function(k, p) {
      c.push($("li", lObj).eq(p.index).detach());
    });
    lObj.append(c);
  }

  function filterList(q, lObj, s) {
    q = q.toLowerCase();
    // Optional perimeter
    if (s == undefined) {
      s = false;
    }
    // Get List Items
    var ls = lObj.children();
    // Hide them all
    ls.addClass("hidden");
    // Array for Filtered/Sorted results
    var results = [];
    // First Pass, Filter by Name
    ls.each(function(i, p) {
      if ($(p).data("name").toLowerCase().indexOf(q) > -1) {
        results.push({
          index: $(p).index(),
          name: $(p).data("name"),
          desc: $(p).data("desc"),
        });
        $(p).removeClass("hidden");
      }
    });
    console.log("P1", results);
    // Second Pass, filter by Desc
    // Skip any already unfiltered
    ls.each(function(i, p) {
      if ($(p).hasClass("hidden") && $(p).data("desc").toLowerCase().indexOf(q) > -1) {
        results.push({
          index: $(p).index(),
          name: $(p).data("name"),
          desc: $(p).data("desc"),
        });
        $(p).removeClass("hidden");
      }
    });
    console.log("P2", results);
    // Array is built with desired filter and sort due to order of operations
    // Check if Element Sort is required
    if (s) {
      sortList(results, lObj);
    }
    // Return Filtered/Sorted Array
    return results;
  }

  $(".filter").keyup(function() {
    $(".hidden").removeClass("hidden");
    if ($(this).val().length > 2) {
      filterList($(this).val(), $(".productList"), true);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Search: <input type="text" class="filter">
<ul class="productList">
  <li data-name="Chocolate Caramels" data-desc="Contains dairy">Chocolate Caramels</li>
  <li data-name="Garlic Mayonnaise" data-desc="Contains egg">Garlic Mayonnaise</li>
  <li data-name="Tomato Egg" data-desc="Contains egg">Tomato Egg</li>
  <li data-name="Scrambled egg" data-desc="Contains egg">Scrambled egg</li>
</ul>
```

Filtering by itself would not sort the elements in the list, so make another function to do that based on the array we built. This detaches them and places them at the end of the list in order, and all other items are hidden.

Answer (score 0):

By using `map()` and `filter()` functions you can loop through the food list items when someone enters search text, and return a list with the search matched items sorted by match type. Here I've added a `.desc` class to the items matched by `data-desc` to distinguish them:

```js
const prods = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("li[productname]")).map(el => el.cloneNode(true));

document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("input", (e) => {

   document.querySelector("#results").innerHTML = "";
   
   const srch = e.target.value;
   
   const nameMatch = prods.filter(item => item.getAttribute("productname").toUpperCase().indexOf(srch.toUpperCase()) > -1);

   const descMatch = prods.filter(item => item.getAttribute("data-desc").toUpperCase().indexOf(srch.toUpperCase()) > -1).filter(item => !nameMatch.includes(item)).map((item) => {
      item.classList = "desc";
      return item;
   });

   const allMatch = nameMatch.concat(descMatch);

   allMatch.forEach((li) => {
      document.querySelector("#results").appendChild(li);
   });

});
```

```css
li.desc {
  color: red;
}

.app {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

h2{
   margin: 16px 0 0;
}
```

```html
Search term: <input type="text" id="search" />
<div class="app">
  <h2>Food Items</h2>
  <h2>Results</h2>
  <ul>
    <li productname="Fruit Punch" data-desc="Fruit juice">Fruit Punch</li>
    <li productname="Fruit Plate" data-desc="Plate with fruit">Fruit Plate</li>
    <li productname="French Toast" data-desc="Bread with syrup and fruit">French Toast</li>
    <li productname="Tomato Egg" data-desc="tomatoes, eggs, bread">Tomato Egg</li>
    <li productname="Scrambled Egg" data-desc="egg and cheese">Scrambled Egg</li>
    <li productname="Garlic Mayonnaise" data-desc="Contains egg">Garlic Mayonnaise</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="results"></ul>

</div>
```